# Where does the date time format coming when use date toLocaleString?

Tags: javascript, datetime, locale

I'm facing some date time formatting related issue.

I'm confused about how a date object's output string is formatted. I did some testing in debug, when I call the toLocalString, the output is not following locale settingin the OS .

Below is the output of the method:
"1/12/2015, 8:12:12 PM"

But what I did in the os locale setting is 
[image]

Why is toLocaleString formatting the date this way? where does those format coming from?
Where to change the format setting browser is using?

Comment: AFAIK `toLocaleString` has nothing to do with the OS's local date format preference settings (although it knows abut the GMT offset on the computer it is running on).

Comment: Yes @torazaburo is right...

Answer (score 1):

*Why is toLocaleString formatting the date this way?*
`toLocaleString()` **doesn't** watch for user's locale formatting settings before returning the string.

*Where does those format coming from?*
The format is based on the conventions of user's time zone for representing date and time. So, format is machine independent.

*Where to change the format setting browser is using?*
As stated the format is implementation dependent. It won't help you anything. And I think browsers don't provide such functionality.

For reference I have included it's documentation below.

The Documentation of `Date.toLocaleString()` as mentioned in [Javascript: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do) says:

> **Returns**
>   A string representation of the date and time specified by date. The date and time are repre- sented in the local time zone and formatted using locally appropriate conventions.
>
> **Usage**
>   `toLocaleString()` converts a date to a string, using the local time zone. This method also uses local conventions for date and time formatting, so the format may vary from platform to platform and from country to country. toLocaleString() returns a string formatted in what is likely the user’s preferred date and time format.